# Powershell - Get the cell location (e.g. B32) after running search for value in Excel document

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

How would you get the the cell location of a value once you have confirmed it exists after a search?

e.g. once the script finds the cell location for "App Name" in each sheet - then I want it to be echoed out to me

```
$i=0
foreach ($b in $b_names)
{
   $b = $b_names[$i]
   $sheet = $wb.Worksheets.Item($b)

   $range = $sheet.Range("B1").EntireColumn
   $s = $range.find("App Name")

   $i=$i+1
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to try.

1. [Message Box](http://powershell-tips.blogspot.com/2012/02/display-messagebox-with-powershell.html)

   ```
   [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Range Found: $s.address().tostring()", "Alert Title")
   ```
2. Write-host

   ```
   write-host "Range found: " $s.address().tostring()
   ```

Comment: When you said 'echoed' out to you I assumed you want the $s variable to be displayed to you for debugging purposes.  You can display the variable by writing a line in the console or by displaying a message box for each one.  Try placing this line before the end of your loop.

Comment: I currently "Range Found: System_ComObject" - how would I get the cell location instead?

Comment: I've tried `[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Range Found: $s.value", "Alert Title")` and I get `Range Found: System_ComObject.value`

Comment: I'm trying to echo the cell location (e.g. B33) where the value `App Name` is found".

Comment: Or this: $s.address().tostring()

Comment: `$s.address().tostring()` worked - thank you so much!